# Is WearableListenerService not affected by background service restriction of android?

Tags: android, wear-os

Hello? I am developing android wear app.

I know that there is a limitation of background service from android 8.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

`WearableListenerService` also extends android `Service`.

But, It seems to be not affected by limitation of background service.

My question is,

Is `WearableListenerService` really not affected by background service restriction of android?